# Скалирование (Scale) картинки в RecyclerView

Tags: android, imageview, recyclerview.adapter

Такая проблем: загружаю в `RecyclerView` картинки, но они не скалируются по высоте (т.е. по ширине сжимаются, а высота остается оригинальной) и картинки становятся вытянутыми. Обычные `ImageView` скалируются (при ограничении ширины высота соответственно уменьшается).

Вопрос: что я пропустил здесь?

Пробовал вручную задавать `LayoutParams` для `ViewHolder` и для `ImageView`, менял в разметке ширину, высоту и тип `scaleType` - не помогает.

Моя разметка:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/gallery_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Мой RecyclerViewAdapter

```
 public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Card> cards;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Card> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Card card = cards.get(i);
        viewHolder.img.setBackgroundResource(card.getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView img;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_img);               
        }
    }
}
```

Мой recycler_item_img

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_item_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ошибся в строчке `viewHolder.img.setBackgroundResource(card.getImage());`

надо `viewHolder.img.setImageResource(card.getImage());`